# Problems with "apt update" in Xubuntu 20.04 -- how do I get the public key for cli.gitub.com

Tags: updates, apt, public-key

I see a problem when I try "apt update" -- here is the output

```
root@camelot-j:/etc/ssh# apt update
Ign:1 http://linux.dropbox.com/ubuntu disco InRelease
Hit:2 http://linux.dropbox.com/ubuntu disco Release                                                                
Hit:3 http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable InRelease                                                       
Hit:5 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal InRelease                                                          
Get:6 https://cli.github.com/packages stable InRelease [3,917 B]                                                   
Hit:7 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates InRelease                                                  
Hit:8 https://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/cuda/repos/ubuntu2004/x86_64  InRelease
Hit:9 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security InRelease
Hit:10 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-backports InRelease
Err:6 https://cli.github.com/packages stable InRelease
  The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 23F3D4EA75716059
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
130 packages can be upgraded. Run 'apt list --upgradable' to see them.
W: An error occurred during the signature verification. The repository is not updated and the previous index files will be used. GPG error: https://cli.github.com/packages stable InRelease: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 23F3D4EA75716059
W: Failed to fetch https://cli.github.com/packages/dists/stable/InRelease  The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 23F3D4EA75716059
W: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
root@camelot-j:/etc/ssh#
```

I do not know what to do about this...

Comment: See https://askubuntu.com/questions/1392394/sudo-apt-update-an-error-occurred-during-the-signature-verification

Comment: @Ramhound YES!! thanks very much.

Comment: "SOLVED" does not belong in your question title. That is what either the automatically applied [duplicate] tag or the tick mark on an answer is for.